# Having notification in system tray makes device slow

Tags: android, push-notification

I have 3 samsung S10 devices, on two of which this problem occurs:

If there is a notification present in the system tray that belongs to the app, it takes the phone about 5 seconds to turn on the screen when clicking the power button.
If there is no notification in the system tray, the screen turns on immediately.
If you manually remove the notification from the system tray, without opening the app, it fixes the issue with the delay in turning on the screen.

What could be causing this problem?

There could only be 1 notification, each new notification replaces the old one.
All the notification does is open the app.
The problem is apparent without opening the app, just having the notification in the tray and the app is not in the background is enough to cause the problem.

The problem is not apparent on any other device that I have.

This is the code that loads the notification into the system tray once it arrives via firebase messaging

```
    private fun sendNotification(message: RemoteMessage) {
    val intent = this.packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(this.packageName)
    intent?.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
    val pendingIntent =
        PendingIntent.getActivity(applicationContext, Random().nextInt(), intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)

    val gson = Gson()
    val jsonData = gson.toJson(message.data)
    val data = gson.fromJson(jsonData, NotificationPayload::class.java)
    if (data.isEmpty()) {
        Timber.i("Was supposed to display notification, but there was no data to display")
        return
    }
    val defaultSoundUri: Uri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION)
    val notificationBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, context.getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification) //
            .setContentTitle(data.title) //
            .setContentText(data.body) //
            .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.very_dark_blue)).setAutoCancel(true) //
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri) //
            .setOnlyAlertOnce(true) //
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent) as NotificationCompat.Builder

    val notificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

    val importance = when(ApplicationForegroundListener.isApplicationForeground()) {
        true -> NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
        else -> NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
    }
    notificationBuilder.priority = importance
    notificationBuilder.setVibrate(LongArray(0))

    // Since android Oreo notification channel is needed.
    val channel = NotificationChannel(context.getString(R.string.app_name),
            context.getString(R.string.app_name),
            importance)
    notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
    notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build())
}
```

Comment: make sure you don't send huge amount of data in notification .

Comment: the data is title and body, both of which don't contain more than 10 characters each

Answer (score 0):

The issue was the size of the notification icon in dp.
I needed to scale it down to 48x48 to fix it.